# Spring - why don't use log4j2 XML configuration file?

Tags: java, xml, spring, configuration, log4j2

Time before I used Log4j ver. 1 in Spring application. I used something like this to define where log4j.properties configuration file resides:

```
PropertyConfigurator.configure(Foo.class.getResourceAsStream("log4j.properties"));
```

Now I switched to Log4j ver. 2 and I have a configuration in XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/' >
    <appenders>    
        <appender name="DB" class="org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender">
            <param name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://hostname/db"/>
            <param name="driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
            <param name="user" value="postgres"/>
            <param name="password" value="pwd"/>
            <param name="sql" value="INSERT INTO logs (logger, log_level, message) VALUES('%l','%p','%m')"/>
            <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"></layout>
        </appender>
        <appender name="CA" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
            <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
                <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
            </layout>
        </appender>
    </appenders> 
    <loggers>
        <root level="trace">
            <appender-ref ref="CA" level="debug"/>
            <appender-ref ref="DB" level="info"/>
        </root>
    </loggers>
</log4j:configuration>
```

But Spring seems don't use this file and logging is not appended into console or database.

```
public class Foo {

    Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(Foo.class);

    public void init() {

        System.out.println("START...");

        LOG.info("INFO");
        LOG.debug("DEBUG");

        System.out.println("END...");

    }
}
```

And this is output:

```
run:
VI 30, 2013 9:36:16 ODP. org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@2548ccb8: startup date [Sun Jun 30 21:36:16 CEST 2013]; root of context hierarchy
VI 30, 2013 9:36:16 ODP. org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [foo/applicationContext.xml]
VI 30, 2013 9:36:16 ODP. org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@21e9c99c: defining beans [taskMaker]; root of factory hierarchy
START...
END...
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 2):

The configuration XML you provided is using the log4j-1.x syntax.
Log4j-2.0 configuration files are different. Please check the web site for examples.

Next, log4j-2.0 will look for log4j2.xml in the classpath.
If you want to specify a location, start your process with system property

```
-Dlog4j.configurationFile=path/to/log4j2.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using gradle and found that logback/slf4j transitive dependencies were getting in the way for me. To remove them, I included:

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude module: 'log4j-over-slf4j'
    all*.exclude group: 'ch.qos.logback'
}
```

in my gradle build file.